# ASP.NET Login Control - How Popular is It?

Tags: asp.net, login-control

Sorry for the weird question.
I'm new to web development (spent the last few years in server side programming).
I'm suppose to write a small web site that will be accessible from the internet and suppose to have users management.

Currently I tend to use the ASP.NET login mechanism (using logic control, etc').

I have two simple questions:
1. Is it something "respected" ASP.NET web sites use?
2. Is it safe enough for the common web site?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in one is fine when you're just building the site and want a quick login page for now that works. It's perfectly safe - probably safer than anything you could build yourself, but I don't know of any "real world" sites that use it...

I have yet to build a single site where I have left it in-place, because there's always going to be a situation where you want to do something it doesn't cater for (for example: it uses a `<table>` which is a pain to style and frowned upon anyway).

Comment: Aside: If you want to use the standard ASP.NET controls but need more control over the markup (or just don't want little <table>s everywhere), have a look at the [CSS Friendly Control Adapters](http://cssfriendly.codeplex.com).

Comment: Yep, the table already started to annoy.
I think I'll follow your advice. I'll start with it, hope to gain some ASP.NET house until the point that I'll have to replace with something of my own.
10x

Answer (score 2):

Haven't seen it a lot on big pages, but it's just nice for a common web site. Nothing to worry about safety. But I always create my own login page/form anyway. If you have time, make your own, if you don't, just use the one.